# One way paging in scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

Is there a way to allow paging in a UIScrollView but restrict the paging to one direction.

For example: Allowing the user to page background (to the left) but not forward. Use case being for some type of onboarding. I know I can add buttons that move forward, have them enabled or disabled, and remove swiping but I rather not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have well understand what you want but what about using a UICollectionView:

```
lazy var onBoardingCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    return cv
}()
```

You add you custom cell with the size of the screen as well by the method in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: SCREENW, height: SCREENH)
}
```

if you don't want to go in a specific direction you can try get the current cell displaying and removing the previous one of the dataSource and collection with this method.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.width)
    print("current cell: ", currentPage)    
}
```